# Can not link Slider marks to TextFields - MaterialUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, material-ui

As you see I want to make slide with 2 marks which represents price between 2 value and handle it on slide. I linked input with slider but slider to input is not working. I tried to implement this function on Slider's onchange. I need to display both data seperately on "From" and "To" Textfields. [**Project link is here**](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-grass-5iidc?file=/src/App.js)

The main problem is here in function. The algorithm is not working good, maybe you could give better solution:

```
const handleSliderFrom = (event, newValue) => {
    if (newValue[0]) {
      if (newValue[0] === 0) {
        setState({ ...state, priceFrom: 15000 });
      } else if (newValue[0] === 20) {
        setState({ ...state, priceFrom: 50000 });
      } else if (newValue[0] === 40) {
        setState({ ...state, priceFrom: 100000 });
      } else if (newValue[0] === 60) {
        setState({ ...state, priceFrom: 200000 });
      } else if (newValue[0] === 80) {
        setState({ ...state, priceFrom: 500000 });
      } else if (newValue[0] === 100) {
        setState({ ...state, priceFrom: 1000000 });
      }
    } else if(newValue[1]){
      if (newValue[1] === 0) {
        setState({ ...state, priceTo: 15000 });
      } else if (newValue[1] === 20) {
        setState({ ...state, priceTo: 50000 });
      } else if (newValue[1] === 40) {
        setState({ ...state, priceTo: 100000 });
      } else if (newValue[1] === 60) {
        setState({ ...state, priceTo: 200000 });
      } else if (newValue[1] === 80) {
        setState({ ...state, priceTo: 500000 });
      } else if (newValue[1] === 100) {
        setState({ ...state, priceTo: 1000000 });
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw 3 main issue in your code:

1 - Your conditions

```
if (newValue[0]) {
```

and

```
if (newValue[1]) {
```

If the value of newValue[0] or newValue[1] is 0, you will not enter in this conditions, so with your actual code you cannot set your value to 0.

2 - You have a lot of conditions when you could use the mark array to get the scaledValue from the value.

3 - You are storing the minimum and maximum prices at 2 different places:

- fromPriceInput and toPriceInput
- state.priceFrom and state.priceTo

As the third issue is not related to your question I'll not cover it in my answer.

I did a simplification of you function covering the first 2 points:

```
  const handleSliderFrom = (event, newValue) => {
    const newPriceFrom = marks.find((mark) => mark.value == newValue[0])
      ?.scaledValue; // search the mark with a value of newValue[0] and returns the scaleValue of this mark
    const newPriceTo = marks.find((mark) => mark.value == newValue[1])
      ?.scaledValue; // search the mark with a value of newValue[1] and returns the scaleValue of this mark
    setState({ priceFrom: newPriceFrom, priceTo: newPriceTo }); // set the store with your new minimum and maximum values (no need to do it one by one, you method will always recieve both)
  };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-hellman-rtdl3?file=/src/App.js:2772-3375

Comment: Appricate your answer, thank you. What would you recommend for third issue? fromPriceInput and toPriceInput, they are for the mark's value which updates slide marks when input changes. What is your solution here?

Comment: I think you should: 
- rename fromPriceInput into fromPrice and toPriceInput into toPrice (it will not only store the input anymore)
- create 2 functions: getValueFromScaledValue and getScaledValueFromValue in order to translate a scaled value into a value (and the opposite)
- store the scaledValue instead of the value in your priceFrom and priceTo
- get rid of the state and directly use priceFrom and priceTo (with the help of the functions created above)